# Listening to WiFi packets

Tags: java, c++, wifi, network-security, network-scan

I'm only in the pre-first stage of the project, so the question is very straight forward and basic. I like to listen to (using Java/C++) every WiFi packets in the range of my laptop, all I care for are the message headers and the very existence of the message so encryption doesn't really play a role here.

Is there a way to get that from Windows(8)/Ubuntu? I didn't manage to find any sort of API form Broadcom, so I guess accessing the card directly won't be trivial. If that's impossible then I could try and do the same with WindowsPhone 8, so if any one know a way for that, it would also be very helpful.

Comment: What's a wifi package? Do you mean packet? You can't snoop on packets using the Windows Phone. I don't understand why you mention Java? Java doesn't run on Windows Phones. Then, you switch to Windows 8 and Linux ... could you please narrow the scope of your question and add more detail about what specific programming issue you're having?

Comment: You're right with the Packets, for some reason I remembered Packages. Never mind, the post was edited. As for the other part of your message, I really don't think it wasn't clear. I want to do it on my laptop and if it's not possible (due to drivers, API, whatever) then my mobile is also an opiton

Comment: This is still far too broad for StackOverflow as written. Do you have a specific programming problem rather than, "how do I listen to Wifi packets?" A better question would include source code you hadn't quite gotten to work for example.

Comment: Yes, I need to save into a db as many packet headers as possible and just as written in the first sentence, I don't have anything yet

Comment: StackOverflow isn't good for "broad" design questions asking for tutorials. Your question is broad enough right now that you haven't even selected an operating system. You could possibly learn (but not copy from) open source projects that have similar functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the links below..

jNetPcap http://jnetpcap.com/examples

WinPcap   https://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_40_2/html/group__wpcapsamps.html

Answer (score 0):

Java isn't very good for this purpose, since this almost directly touches very basics of your machine. You should take a look at "Windows driver kit" and consider using lower level language like C++ for this. Although even then, you will run into obstacles like anti-virus software, trying to block your package sniffing.