# Java - Wait until a new device connects to your local network

Tags: java, networking, wifi

I'd like to write a simple server-side program that waits until a new device connects to my local network (respectively WIFI).

Basically what I want to achieve is a Java program running on my computer (which is connected to the WIFI) waiting for my phone to connect to the WIFI whenever I come home and running some code afterwards. There's no seperate app running on the phone, the only thing the program is looking at is the network.

Any ideas how this is possible? Thanks for your time!

Comment: 1 sec of using google and i get a result which you could work with.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22437752/listening-to-wifi-packets

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is used a Process.class and call [Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_(networking_utility)) and then parse a result.

Comment: Haven't tried it out yet but this way you would need to periodically call ping to see if there're any new devices inside the network, right? Is there a way to get some kind of notification (maybe directly from the router) and run a callback method?